# When testing Room AutoMigrations, what do I pass to runMigrationsAndValidate?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-testing

When using [Room AutoMigrations](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-auto-migrations-d5370b0ca6eb), the `Migration` itself is automatically generated. But in order to [unit test the migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#test), I have to pass a `Migration` object to `runMigrationsAndValidate`. What should I pass here?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MigrationTest {
    private val TEST_DB = "migration-test"

    @Rule
    val helper: MigrationTestHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
            MigrationDb::class.java.canonicalName,
            FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory()
    )

    @Test
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun migrate1To2() {
        var db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 1).apply {
            // db has schema version 1. insert some data using SQL queries.
            execSQL(...)

            // Prepare for the next version.
            close()
        }

        // Re-open the database with version 2 and provide
        // Migration as the migration process.
        db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true, /* WHAT TO PASS HERE? */)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the first db initialization if you are reinitializing it below?

Answer (score 8):

As far as i understand, in the new AutoMigration, we are not required to handle migrations ourself.

So at first, update your `MigrationTestHelper` to a API which supports AutoMigration:

```
import androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry

val helper = MigrationTestHelper(
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
    YourDatabase::class.java
)
```

And then just remove the Migration from the call:

`db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true)`

Comment: We can now just remove the empty ArrayList and just use the constructor like so:
```MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(), Database::class.java)```